# Non-standard ToC style

Tags: table-of-contents, section-titles

I'm preparing my thesis in LYX.
Text is in russian, but there are a lot of symbols and chemical formulas in english. By now I work with "extended article" class, standard.
I need to make a ToC looking similar to this example (the rules for thesis style are quite strict):
[image]

So I need to use some special commands to change section titles and numbering. But I'm not familiar with this "fine-tuning". Are there any useful commands or some package that can easily help?

Code in .tex file:

```
 \documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[LGR,T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=1.1cm,headheight=17pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{subscript}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand*\LyXZeroWidthSpace{\hspace{0pt}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\greektext}{%
  \fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{LGR}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textgreek}[1]{\leavevmode{\greektext #1}}
\ProvideTextCommand{\~}{LGR}[1]{\char126#1}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyrtext}{%
  \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{T2A}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textcyr}[1]{\leavevmode{\cyrtext #1}}

\newcommand{\lyxmathsym}[1]{\ifmmode\begingroup\def\b@ld{bold}
  \text{\ifx\math@version\b@ld\bfseries\fi#1}\endgroup\else#1\fi}

\ProvideTextCommandDefault{\guillemotleft}{%
  {\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\char'50\kern-.15em\char'50}%
\penalty10000\hskip0pt\relax%
}
\ProvideTextCommandDefault{\guillemotright}{%
  \penalty10000\hskip0pt%
  {\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\char'51\kern-.15em\char'51}%
}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textquotedbl}{T1}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{Sect }
%\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{6em}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0}
%\renewcommand \thepart {\arabic\part}

\makeatother

\usepackage[style=gost-numeric,bibencoding=utf8, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{0C__Users_1_Documents_My_diss_All_bib.bib}
\begin{document}

\rhead{}
\chead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\begin{center}
{\large{}Титульная}\newpage{}
\par\end{center}

\tableofcontents 
\clearpage

\newpage{}

\part*{{\large{}Введение }}

\section*{{\normalsize{}Цели диссертационной работы}}

\section*{{\normalsize{}Апробация работы} }

Основные результаты диссертационной работы были представлены в виде ..

\newpage{}
\part{{\normalsize{}Литературный обзор}}

\vspace{42pt}

\section{{\normalsize{}Природа обменного взаимодействия}}

\vspace{42pt}

\section{{\normalsize{}Обменные взаимодействия в соединениях РЗМ с Fe, Ni,
Mn}}

\vspace{42pt}
В интерметаллических соединениях РЗМ с 3d переходными металлами..

\newpage{}
\part{{\normalsize{}Технология приготовления и аттестация образцов }}

\vspace{42pt}

\section{{\normalsize{}Микроструктура }}
\section{{\normalsize{}Измерение температуры Кюри и намагниченности }}
\section{{\normalsize{}Методика измерения ... }}

\vspace{42pt}

\newpage{}
\part{{\normalsize{}Результаты}}

\vspace{42pt}

\section{{\normalsize{}Гигантская ... }}


\section{{\normalsize{}Магнитные свойства..}}

\newpage{}
\part{Выводы}

\section*{\newpage Литература}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Command "\cftchappresnum" didn't work for some reason - I've put it in comment in example above.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I know three main packages for standard classes: `tocloft`, `titletoc` (which is a comonent of `titlesec`) and `etoc`.

Answer (score 2):

As you have not provided an MWE I do not know how you have added your first, and later, unnumbered entries to the ToC. I don't read Russian; the following is in English and I hope that you are more multilingual than I am.

The `tocloft` package can be of some help.

```
% tocrussianprob.tex  SE 561296

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% centering the ToC title
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
% put section before section entries
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{Section }
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{5em} % need more space for Section + num

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A sub-subsection}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{A subsection with a very long title, I hope it's over one line in the ToC}
\end{document}
```

I don't know how to get the second line of a title to be at the left margin. The normal typographic style is for the titles to be aligned as a block.

Comment: Thanks for reply @peter-wilson. But I've found that one didn't work for me. The command "\cftsecpresnum" you mentioned changes the Section, while I need to change the Chapter. When I tried to insert command "\cftchappresnum", LaTex showd an error. Below I put a code which goes to preamble in my file.

Comment: @Alexandra: Can you expand that preamble into a **minimal working example**? The idea with a MWE is that it should be *working*, i.e. a complete document that we can directly put into a file and compile; an *example* in that it contains everything in your document that seems relevant to the issue (a couple of `\section` commands, say, and also any code that you expect to interact with the TOC/sectioning), but *minimal* in that anything irrelevant to this issue is stripped out — the document text, packages that don’t affect the TOC, etc. That will make it much easier for answerers to help you!

Comment: Thanks for reply! @peter-lefanu-lumsdaine I've edited my question

Comment: @Alexandra Your MWE uses the `extarticle` class and I have no idea where I can get that from. In general `article` classes do not provide `\chapter` command and you have not used `\chapter` in your MWE. I'm not surprised that `\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum{...}` does not work in a document that does not know about `\chapter`. I have no idea how to help you with the information you have provided.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that dealing with "chapter" isn't supported by article class. I've found that it would be better to use report class instead. I'll post a new question, because some points aren't clear yet.